# Using both kafka 2.10 and 2.11 in one project (one for test)

Tags: maven, maven-dependency

I have a maven project that uses another package that uses kafka client version `kafka_2.10`. In the test of my project, I'd like to use `kafka_2.11` because all our other projects use `kafka_2.11` and we have some code that I can reuse.

The desired dependency structure is the following as of right now:

```
MyProject ---> SomebodyElsesPackage ---> kafka_2.10
   |
   ---> test --> kafka_2.11
```

Is this possible or am I stuck with `kafka_2.10`?